# Google playstore console not showing policy compliance option while i publish the new update under Locations Permission App Content

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-play-services, native

My Native Android application rejected in google Playstore more than 2 times. After Spending some time, found the content is not listed in Playstore while uploading and publishing app in Playstore. In App Content -> Locations Permissions, the sample highlighted option is not listed for one of my application while publishing the new update in Playstore.

[image]

I just know the reason, is it because of region specific or Am i missing anything in my Android Manifest, etc?